# Configure multiple build variant in Android Studio and Firebase Console in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-analytics

Initially I configured my application to Firebase console with Events and Reports, etc., are showing in Fire base console. But I have 3 build environment like Debug, Staging & Production. I would like to show individual report based on environment which is configured in build Apk.

My concern is, how to configure multiple build variant in studio and Firebase console?

Comment: please try this link. https://medium.com/@Miqubel/multiple-build-types-in-firebase-on-android-6f6715f6dd83